# Add date to feature class name?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, shapefile, file-geodatabase

I still working on my big project, big at least for me, but I am currently stuck on this:

I have a lots of .shp, that I want to move to a gdb. While creating a feature class, I want 
to add date (YMD) before the name: test.shp -> _120706_test

Possibly the creation date of the SHP but also the importing date will be ok.

I created a list of feature and tried: _fc  = *'*' + fc but it is not working.

```
# Import system modules 
import sys, arcpy, datetime, os, traceback, time 
from arcpy import env 

# Load required toolboxes... 
arcpy.AddToolbox("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.0\\ArcToolbox\\Toolboxes\\Data Management Tools.tbx")


# Get the active map document 
import arcpy.mapping 
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument ("CURRENT") 

# List broken links 
# arcpy.mapping.ListBrokenDataSources(mxd) 

# Set environment settings 
ws = "C:\\PARK" 
arcpy.env.workspace = ws 
print("env.workspace completed successfully") 
installdir = arcpy.GetInstallInfo("desktop") 

#check GDB exist 
gdb_nam = "test.gdb" 
gdb_full_path = os.path.join(ws,gdb_nam) 
if os.path.exists(gdb_full_path): 
    arcpy.Delete_management(gdb_full_path) 
print("GDB checked") 

# Execute CreateFileGDB 
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(ws, gdb_nam) 
print("CreateFileGDB completed successfully") 
outWorkspace = gdb_full_path 

# Create a list of SHP in mxd 
list = [] 

for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames (mxd): 
    for fc in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers (mxd, "", df):
        if (fc.supports("DATASOURCE")) and (fc.dataSource.endswith(".shp")):
                    list.append(fc)

# Check for borken datasource
for fc in list:
    if arcpy.mapping.ListBrokenDataSources(fc):
        list.remove(fc)

# Check for projection



# Move fc to gdb
for fc in list:
    rename (fc,'_'+fc.name)
    arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(fc, gdb_full_path)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that jumps out is: the [rename](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000056000000) command should be:

`arcpy.Rename_management(in_data, out_data, data_type)`

Comment: Using this command would be an unnecessary step. Instead I would use [FeatureClassToFeatureClass](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000020000000) which lets you specify the desired output feature class name.

Comment: that is what I did and it works, point is it creates new layers and add them to the current mxd, why?

Answer (score 6):

This may help to find the created date: [How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python)

You'll probably want to read up on the [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) and [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) modules and string formatting in Python ([new](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#new-string-formatting) or [old](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) styles).

Here is a small example to hopefully get you going:

```
import os, datetime

fc = r"C:\GISData\atlantic_hurricanes_2000.shp"
ctime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(fc))
ymd = ctime.strftime("%Y%m%d")
inputFcName = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fc))[0]
outputFcName = "%s_%s" % (ymd, inputFcName)

print outputFcName # prints 20120315_atlantic_hurricanes_2000
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that asap. But will converto to gdb let me use numbers as first in the name?

Comment: I think not actually. Adjust as needed.

Comment: Hi there, the solution you suggested ain't working cause with list I created a list of object that can be renamed using rename. Any Idea?

Comment: Please update your question with the new information and code. Also "ain't working" doesn't explain much.

Answer (score 0):

I always do something like:

```
from time import strftime
outFile = "myfeatureClassName" + "_" + strftime("%d%b%y")
```

and then just use the 'outFile' variable for your output parameter on whichever geoprocessing tool you are using. The syntax inside brackets of the strftime function can changes the date format. Here's a decent look at the different types:

http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime